# How do you handle with control binding in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about jquery and DOM manipulation. How do you handle with DOM controls for e.g.

I have to get value from text input so I could this in ways:

```
var SomeClass = function() {
    var control;

    this.setControl = function(c) {
        control = c;
    }

    this.getValue = function() {
        return control.val();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var sc = new SomeClass(); // of course control could be passed in contructor as well
    sc.setControl($('#CONTROL'));
    console.log(sc.getValue());
});
```

**OR**

```
var SomeClass = function() {
    var control = $('#CONTROL');

    this.getValue = function() {
        return control.val();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var sc = new SomeClass();
    console.log(sc.getValue());
});
```

what is your opinion? What is better or maybe this is pile of trash therefore what is the best solution. Plz dont send me to backbone, spine and so on Im interesed in only in jquery.

best!

EDIT:

do you separate logic from UI or you are mixing it? 
more complicated example

in js file you have a class that uses text control and in the secound js file also you need values from this input. What you are doing? you just call everytime $('#control') or create a third js file where would be a separated "class" to manipulate this input?

Comment: I don't think this gives you any added benefits

Comment: There is no need to bind control to classes, just directly bind it to var, it's OK in js.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to move the setValue() inside the constructor:

```
SomeClass = function(c) {
    var control = c;

    return {
        getValue: function() {
            return control.val();
        }
    }
}

var x = new SomeClass($('input'));

alert(x.getValue());
```

However, I'm not sure how valuable this kind of information hiding will be. Perhaps as some kind of view wrapper.

In many cases you wouldn't need this wrapper, so just:

```
var $x = $('input'); // keep reference to a bunch of <input> elements.
```

Comment: passing in a constructor does make sence but Im wondering if @sayume (plz look at the comment on the top) is right: "Just directly bind it to var, it's OK in js" - maybe creating class that wraps control isn't a good idee at all? maybe calling $('#xxx') its okey everytime when its needed?

Comment: using var to bind control is to avoid call"$('#XXX')"every time, The dom element is stored temporarily and you can access it without searching the dom tree every time, that's the idea.

Comment: @reizals Since the most important bit is to "cache" the dom references, jQuery objects themselves are good enough in most cases.